# Find it's radius of convergence, interval of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x+2)^n}{n2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, power-series, absolute-convergence

> Consider the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x+2)^n}{n2^n}$$
> Find it's radius of convergence, interval of convergence. Also find for which $x$ the series is absolutely convergent and conditionally convergent.

**My attempt :**
Let, $$a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n2^n}$$
Then by **ratio test** we have the radius of convergence, $$\rho = \lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}| = \frac{1}{2}$$

Then the interval of convergence is $$ |x+2| \lt \frac{1}{2} \\
\implies x \in (-\frac{5}{2},-\frac{3}{2})$$

We know that in the interval of convergence the power series is absolutely convergent. So we now check the absolute convergence at the end points.

For $x= -\frac{5}{2}$, the series becomes,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{n2^{2n}}$$ which is absolutely convergent and that can be tested using the comparison test with the series $\sum \frac{1}{4^n}$.

For $x = -\frac{3}{2}$,the series becomes,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n2^{2n}}$$ which is also absolutely convergent and that can be tested using the comparison test with the series $\sum \frac{1}{4^n}$.

Is my answer correct? Can anyone please confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)2^{n+1}}{n2^n}=2,$$and therefore the radius of convergence is $2$, not $\frac12$. So, your series converges absolutely on $(-4,0)$ and diverges when $x\notin[-4,0]$.

If $x=0$, then your series is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$, which converges conditionally. And if $x=-4$, then your series is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac1n$, which diverges.

Comment: You're right. I made an error while putting the values of $a_n$'s.

Comment: Then what should I write about the interval of convergence? In my book it's written as $|x-a| \lt \rho$. But at $0$ it converges.

Comment: The set of points at which the series converge is the interval $[0,4)$. Perhaps that your textbook calls “interval of convergence” to the set of those $x$'s such that $|x-a|$ is smaller than the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way,  with Cauchy-Hadamard.

$r=\frac1{\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}}=\frac1{\limsup \frac1 {|n2^n|^{1/n}}}=\frac1{{\limsup}\frac1{\sqrt[n] n\cdot 2}}=\frac1{\frac12}=2$.